# WSO2ESB scripting in Groovy 2.4

Tags: wso2-esb

I would like to use groovy 2.4 as my scripting language in WSO2ESB.
I have added groovy-all 2.4 to the libS but it looks like wso2esb completely ignores that script in synapses.

Does wso2esb 4.8.1 supports groovy 2.4?
How can I integrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where exactly did you put the groovy-all jar ?

I´ve added the groovy-all-2.4.4.jar inside the $CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib and it seems to work ok.

Below is a sample proxy that you can use in order to check the groovy version that the ESB is picking:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="groovytest"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <script language="groovy">def  version = GroovySystem.version
mc.setProperty("groovyVersion",version);</script>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <r:response xmlns:r="http://test/response">
                  <r:groovyVersion>$1</r:groovyVersion>
               </r:response>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('groovyVersion')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

When I call is from the "TryIt" page, I get the following answer:

```
<r:response xmlns:r="http://test/response">
   <r:groovyVersion>2.4.4</r:groovyVersion>
</r:response>
```